# My transaction is pending and it seems like doesnt execute the transaction at all?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, erc-20, myetherwallet, etherscan

I wanted to transfer ERC20 tokens from MEW to another ERC20 token wallet. It seems like not moving. Now my transaction is pending and it doesn't showing up in myetherwallet as a pending status. Can this transaction be automatically cancelled or I have to do something? (transaction is not showing up in Check TX Status on MEW, please help)

Tx Hash : 0xecf3911df3636c242f48921d241ecb8e313e40361fb6f0dc02c66ebf45a5dc21

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the [transaction on Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xecf3911df3636c242f48921d241ecb8e313e40361fb6f0dc02c66ebf45a5dc21) you can see that the transaction was dropped & replaced, meaning you sent a different transaction to replace this one with the same nonce.

You can find more information about nonce [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/transactions/what-is-nonce.html).